# How to set up server authentication in Apache MINA sshd?

Tags: java, sshd, mina

I have set up an ssh server using Apache MINA sshd for SFTP. I want to enable server authentication so clients cannot be spoofed. In the documentation page all it says is to use the following method ([Apache MINA sshd doc](https://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/embedding_ssh.html)):

```
sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new SimpleGeneratorHostKeyProvider("hostkey.ser"));
```

But as I understand, that generates a keypair on its own. What if I want to use an existing certificate file for this server?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it. I used the MappedKeyPairProvider class:

```
sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new MappedKeyPairProvider(loadKeyPair("certificateFile.p12")));
```

With loadKeyPair defined as follows:

```
public static loadKeyPair(String path) throws KeyStoreException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchProviderException {
    KeyStore p12 = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
    p12.load(new FileInputStream(path), "certPassword".toCharArray());
    java.security.cert.Certificate cert = p12.getCertificate("myAlias");
    PublicKey publicKey = cert.getPublicKey();
    PrivateKey key = (PrivateKey)p12.getKey("myAlias", "certPassword".toCharArray());
    return new KeyPair(publicKey, key);
}
```

Please note that my certificate is stored in PKCS12 format.

Comment: Did you find so way to configure authentication if running bin\sshd.bat?

Comment: No, sorry. I did it all programatically.

Comment: Thanks! For anyone who stumble accross this: the integrated authentication is fixed to "Objects.equals(username, password)", so you can logon e.g. as "root", "root".

Answer (score 0):

FileKeyPairProvider is simpler

```
Path path = Paths.get(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("server-key.pem").toURI());
sshd.setKeyPairProvider(new FileKeyPairProvider(path));
```

Comment: If you package your application, will this still work? I feel `FileKeyPayProvider` expects a physical file, and this would only work during development because calling `.toURI` on a resource is still able to produce a `file://` URI.

Comment: Found `ClassLoadableResourceKeyPairProvider`.